# add array values to csv file column failed

Tags: java, arrays, csv

I want add value in last column from array values but the result is wrong. I have 3 files for testing. first, my file contains:

```
row1-1  row1-2
row2-1  row2-2
```

and I want the result:

```
row1-1  row1-2  newstring1
row2-1  row2-2  newstring2
```

but my result: (notes: with 3 files, first file the result below but others file empty)

```
row1-1  row1-2  newstring1
row2-1  row2-2  newstring1
```

I have problem in my while, when I print "i" below "i++ code" in console, the program ran be like (in while):
result
write
i++ (print: i=1)
i++ (print: i=2)

why the code ran be like this? after print i=1 and then i=2. so, show error array index. how to fix this problem? I want create be like unique id each column. thanks.

my code:

```
String [] addedColumn = {"newstring1", "newstring2"};

try {
    session = jsch.getSession("hpx", "10.170.49.20", 22);
    session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
    session.setPassword("mypassword");
    session.connect();

    Channel channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
    channel.connect();
    ChannelSftp sftpChannel = (ChannelSftp) channel;

    Vector<ChannelSftp.LsEntry> list = sftpChannel.ls(path_sftp + "*.ONPROGRESS");
    Vector<ChannelSftp.LsEntry> listFile = sftpChannel.ls(path_sftp + "*.txt");
    Vector<ChannelSftp.LsEntry> listOK = sftpChannel.ls(path_sftp + "*.OK");

    String fileNameEntry = null;
    String result = "";
    int i=0;

    if (list.isEmpty()) {
        for (ChannelSftp.LsEntry entry : listFile) {
            fileNameEntry = entry.getFilename();

            // Create new Extention file
            newFile = fileNameEntry.split("\\.", -1);   

            // Copy file to Local
            sftpChannel.get(path_sftp + entry.getFilename(), path_local_input + entry.getFilename());

            try {
                br = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(path_local_input + fileNameEntry)));
                bw = new BufferedWriter(
                        new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(path_local_output + fileNameEntry)));
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                        result = "\t" + addedColumn[i];
                        bw.write(line + result + System.lineSeparator());
                        i++;
                }
                br.close();
                bw.close();
            } catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println(e);
            } 
        }
    }
    sftpChannel.exit();
    session.disconnect();
} catch (JSchException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (SftpException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the code that i see, you have a for loop at start for list of files and a while loop which iterates over the contents of file. Now if you are going to have multiple files to be read, then you need to initialize the variable "i" inside the for loop to 0. That is why it is throwing index out of bounds exceptions. Also the array "addedColumn" has length 2. So i am expecting that when you are iterating over file content you just have two records, if in case you have more than two records then again it is going to throw index out of bounds exception.

Let me know in case you need some more clarification.